# Just updated to Yosemite. YouTube, Flash, plays in Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, update, flash, mac

I don't think I installed anything to to bypass Tor's non-Flash settings, but I seem to be able to play YouTube videos in my Tor Browser.

By the way, not sure if this has anything to do it, but I just, finally, upgraded to Yosemite. Too, I live in the U.A.E. in the Middle East and installed Yosemite here, not in the U.S. or Europe.

**Has my computer been compromised (spyware, etc.)? Will it be compromised if I'm able to use Flash on Tor Browser** Or does Yosemite or the new Tor Browser update now allow Flash, YouTubes to be played?

Comment: It's possible you're viewing the HTML5 version of the YouTube video, and not the Flash version. (In fact, that should be the default mode.) Check some other sites that include Flash and see if they work or not.

Comment: Hi Rich. It is indeed HTML5. A quick right-click just revealed that. Thank you for you insight. Sorry about my paranoid, freak-out. I just remember not having any videos play while using Tor Browser under Mavericks. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem - it's better to be safe than sorry :)